# download pdf with guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, php-5.4

I want to download a pdf file with guzzle. Is this possible?

I tried this code:

```php
$response  = $this->client->post(self::API_BASE_URL.self::API_LABEL_URL,
                    [
                            'future' => true,
                            'json' => [$this->json],
                            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/pdf'],
                            'query' => [
                                        'return-type' => 'pdf',
                                        'x-api-key'   => $this->apiKey
                            ],
                     ]);
```

and I get

```
[body] => GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream Object(
[stream:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => Resource id #120
[size:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 649
[seekable:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 1
[readable:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 1
[writable:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 1
[uri:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => php://temp
[customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => Array
```

But I don't have an idea how I can handle this Resource id to save the pdf file.
I use guzzle 5.3 and PHP 5.4 with no options to update the php version.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? What's the problem with that code?

Comment: I don't know the next step.

Comment: What is the next step? What does not work yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guzzle **sink** option to download file - http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#sink

```
$pdfFilePath = __DIR__ . '/resource/file.pdf'; // specify your path
$pdfFileResource = fopen($pdfFilePath, 'w+');

$this->client->post(
    self::API_BASE_URL . self::API_LABEL_URL,
    [
        'future' => true,
        'json' => [$this->json],
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
            'Accept' => 'application/pdf'
        ],
        'query' => [
            'return-type' => 'pdf',
            'x-api-key'   => $this->apiKey
        ],
        'sink' => $pdfFileResource
    ]
);
```

More examples - https://github.com/andriichuk/php-curl-cookbook#download-file